# 'updateMenu' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, arduino

1. I refer this code from the youtube, when i run it, the updateMenu is defined. But when i changed it, suddenly it does not define
2. I get the code from this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuAG98P9Seo
3. The actual one only use LCD Display with the pushbutton, and I want to add a keypad to modified the code
4. As can see the error says

   > 'updateMenu' was not declared in this scope
   >   [image]

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

int upButton = 10;
int downButton = 11;
int selectButton = 12;
int menu = 1;
const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 3; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'#','0','*'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin();
  lcd.backlight();
  pinMode(upButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(downButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(selectButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  updateMenu();
}

void loop() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key != No_Key){
    Serial.print(key);
  }
  {
  if (!digitalRead(downButton)){
    menu++;
    updateMenu();
    delay(100);
    while (!digitalRead(downButton));
  }
  if (!digitalRead(upButton)){
    menu--;
    updateMenu();
    delay(100);
    while(!digitalRead(upButton));
  }
  if (!digitalRead(selectButton)){
    executeAction();
    updateMenu();
    delay(100);
    while (!digitalRead(selectButton));
  }
}

void updateMenu() {
  switch (menu) {
    case 0:
      menu = 1;
      break;
    case 1:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(">Find Existing File");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(" Select File");
      break;
    case 2:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(">Custom Setting");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("Create/Delete File");
      break;
    case 3:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(">MenuItem3");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(" MenuItem4");
      break;
    case 4:
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print(" MenuItem3");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(">MenuItem4");
      break;
    case 5:
      menu = 4;
      break;
  }
}

void executeAction() {
  switch (menu) {
    case 1:
      action1();
      break;
    case 2:
      action2();
      break;
  }
}

void action1() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(">Select File 0 to 99");
  delay(1500);
}
void action2() {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print(">Create File");
  delay(1500);
}
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: put `void updateMenu();` just after the `#include ..` lines

Comment: you have a superfluous { in loop() before `if (!digitalRead(downButton)){`

Comment: Try to add `void updateMenu();` line before `void setup() {` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In place of usage compiler don't know about `updateMenu()` function, so you should tell him about this function earlier by simple declaration of `updateMenu()` function.

To do this, you need to place below line:

```cpp
void updateMenu();
```

before definition of `setup()` function:

```cpp
...
void updateMenu();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
...
```

P.S By default CPP programmer put declaration of their functions (if needed) on the top of their code (just after the `#include` lines).